# Why is it that the data from the $http service cannot be obtained?

Tags: angularjs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>First AngularJS Application</title>
    <script src="scripts/angular.js"></script>

</head>
<body ng-app = "myAngularApp">
<div>
        <div ng-controller="myController">
            Response Data: {{data}} <br />
            Error: {{error}}
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        var myApp = angular.module('myAngularApp', []);

        myApp.controller("myController", function ($scope, $http) {

            var onSuccess = function (data, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.data = data;
            };

            var onError = function (data, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.error = status;
            }

            var promise = $http.get("index.html");

            promise.success(onSuccess);
            promise.error(onError);

        });
    </script>
</body>
```

[This is the html file and when I load the page the data were not retrieved. I'm not sure if I have some little mistakes since I copy pasted it in the tutorial.
This will be the output.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hi7Ap.png)

[Folder Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HfMVo.png)

Comment: your angular file is present on this location in your project scripts/angular.js ???

Comment: Yeah it is. I already tried with angular js events and it's working but I'm having trouble with this one

Comment: Show your folder structure and what version of angular are you using?

Comment: @Peterhdd it's still the same

Comment: @Vivz you can click the folder structure to see

Comment: @JJJ Did you change your script tag src?

Comment: @Vivz yeah but it's still not working. I have downloaded 1.6.x version of angular.js. I don't know if the service is supported in that version

Comment: @JJJ I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script tag is wrong in your case. You are using lowercase in your code but your folder structure shows uppercase **Scripts**

```
<script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
```

**Update**
If you are using latest version of angularjs, try the below code since success and error are deprecated.

```
 var myApp = angular.module('myAngularApp', []);

        myApp.controller("myController", function ($scope, $http) {

            var onSuccess = function (data) {
                $scope.data = data.data;
            };

            var onError = function (data) {
                $scope.error = data;
            }

            var promise = $http.get("index.html");

            promise.then(onSuccess);
            promise.catch(onError);

        });
```

**For more Info** : [Why are angular $http success/error methods deprecated? Removed from v1.6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35329384/why-are-angular-http-success-error-methods-deprecated-removed-from-v1-6)

Answer (score -1):

Use **then** rather than **success** and use **catch** rather than **error**

Example:

```
<div>
    <div ng-controller="myController">
        Response Data: <span ng-bind-html="data"></span> <br />
        Error: {{error}}
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    var myApp = angular.module('myAngularApp', []);

    myApp.controller("myController", function ($scope, $http, $sce) {

        var onSuccess = function (data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.data = $sce.trustAsHtml(data.data);
        };

        var onError = function (data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.error = data;
        }

        var promise = $http.get("index.html");

        promise.then(onSuccess);
        promise.catch(onError);

    });
</script>
```

Comment: `success`, and `error` are completely valid unless the Angular version is specified by OP.

Comment: I have updated code to show html... used **$sce.trustAsHtml** and **ng-bind-html**

Comment: you can see [official documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce) of **$sce** [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce)

Comment: No data value and error value can be seen. Output in the page is just:
Response Data:
Error:

Comment: on view side you have to use
**<span ng-bind-html="data"></span>**

and in controller inject **$sce**

and then mark response data as trusted html
**$sce.trustAsHtml(data.data);**

Comment: One more thing to be noted... You have currently opened index.html file. and again you are loading index.html file. I will suggest you to create another html file and request it...

Comment: Here is working [plunkr ...http://plnkr.co/edit/CxuMx8XuVzoUOS1RGMiT?p=preview](http://plnkr.co/edit/CxuMx8XuVzoUOS1RGMiT?p=preview)